# How do I use drivers to endlessly loop something spinning forward and in reverse back and forth?

Tags: drivers

I've created an animated scene that has a series of shapes that rotate endlessly using drivers. I do not want to key any animation.

I found a tutorial for a spinning portal on YouTube that uses the #frame command to spin an image of noise around on a flat plane. All the other shapes in the scene need to endlessly loop in the same direction. However, I need the spinning portal to switch direction so that, for half the animation it spins one way and for the other half of the animation loop it spins the opposite way.

If this helps at all, it has to do with the degrees of rotation and not the number of frames. For instance the one shape, an orb, rotates 360 degrees but also, so does the portal (rather the portal orbits). The difference though is that when the swirling portal reaches the 180 degree mark of its orbit, it then needs to reverse the direction the portal is swirling in.

Here is a link to the portal tutorial I used, [Create an interdimensional Portal in 3D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4_JLFU5nj4&list=PLTf3nduuWRCrqE_nEA6LtxJVWmn-ZgMzP&index=4)

Answer (score 1):

Looping a rotation that goes back and forth is actually trivial, because you simply animate it to go forward, then back, and so it returns to its original state and the animation can repeat.

Assuming you don't want the rotation to suddenly switch directions and you want easing, so a sinusoide is perfect for that:

[image]

switching rotation direction thrice within 10 frames is definitely too sudden. Also the rotation should go from $0$ to $π$, or from $-π \over 2$ to $+π \over 2$ or you know otherwise $π$ range ($π$ rad $ = 180°$).

So as the `sin()` operates on radians and has a repeating period of range $-π..+π$, we want to:

- Calculate the percentage of animation, for an animation going from frame #1 to frame #200 it's $x \over 200$, where $x$ is the frame number
- multiply this percentage by the range `sin` expects, so by $τ = 2π$
- the output of `sin` is $-1..+1$, so this time need to convert in the other way, either normalize and multiply by the desired range $π$, or multiply by half of the desired range (because half negative and half positive give you the whole range).

[image]

The driver: `sin(frame*tau/200)*pi/2`

[image]